# how to impute a value in particular columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

i have a column called gender in which there is few misspelled word  and 'f' .
I tried imputing in the below way but it imputed all the columns.

```
df[df['Gender'] == 'F' ] = 'abc'
```

output:

```
EmployeeID  Attrition   Age TravelProfile   Department  HomeToWork  EducationField  Gender  HourlnWeek  Involvement ... JobSatisfaction ESOPs   NumCompaniesWorked  OverTime    SalaryHikelastYear  WorkExperience  LastPromotion   CurrentProfile  MaritalStatus   MonthlyIncome
0   abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc ... abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
19  abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc ... abc abc
```

how to overcome this? and impute only gender column

Comment: `df.loc[df['Gender'] == 'F', 'Gender' ] = 'abc'` or `df['Gender'] = df['Gender'].replace('F', 'abc')`.

Answer (score 1):

`df.loc[df['Gender'] == 'F', 'Gender' ] = 'abc'` should work! You have to index with `loc` and specify the row and column!